# Compare current row value to previous row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have login history data from User A for a day. My requirement is that at any point in time the User A can have only one valid login. As in the samples below, the user may have attempted to login successfully multiple times, while his first session was still active. So, any logins that happened during the valid session needs to be flagged as duplicate.

**Example 1:**

In the first sample data below, while the user was still logged in from `00:12:38` to `01:00:02 (index 0)`, there is another login from the user at `00:55:14` to `01:00:02 (index 1)`.

Similarly, if we compare `index 2` and `3`, we can see that the record at `index 3` is duplicate login as per requirement.

```
  start_time  end_time
0   00:12:38  01:00:02
1   00:55:14  01:00:02
2   01:00:02  01:32:40
3   01:00:02  01:08:40
4   01:41:22  03:56:23
5   18:58:26  19:16:49
6   20:12:37  20:52:49
7   20:55:16  22:02:50
8   22:21:24  22:48:50
9   23:11:30  00:00:00
```

**Expected output:**

```
  start_time  end_time   isDup
0   00:12:38  01:00:02       0
1   00:55:14  01:00:02       1
2   01:00:02  01:32:40       0
3   01:00:02  01:08:40       1
4   01:41:22  03:56:23       0
5   18:58:26  19:16:49       0
6   20:12:37  20:52:49       0
7   20:55:16  22:02:50       0
8   22:21:24  22:48:50       0
9   23:11:30  00:00:00       0
```

These duplicate records need to be updated to 1 at column `isDup`.

---

**Example 2:**

Another sample of data as below. Here, while the user was still logged in between `13:36:10` and `13:50:16`, there were 3 additional sessions too that needs to be flagged.

```
  start_time  end_time
0   13:32:54  13:32:55
1   13:36:10  13:50:16
2   13:37:54  13:38:14
3   13:46:38  13:46:45
4   13:48:59  13:49:05
5   13:50:16  13:50:20
6   14:03:39  14:03:49
7   15:36:20  15:36:20
8   15:46:47  15:46:47
```

**Expected output:**

```
  start_time    end_time    isDup
0   13:32:54    13:32:55    0
1   13:36:10    13:50:16    0
2   13:37:54    13:38:14    1
3   13:46:38    13:46:45    1
4   13:48:59    13:49:05    1
5   13:50:16    13:50:20    0
6   14:03:39    14:03:49    0
7   15:36:20    15:36:20    0
8   15:46:47    15:46:47    0
```

---

What's the efficient way to compare the start time of the current record with previous records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the `time` like values in columns `start_time` and `end_time` to pandas `TimeDelta` objects and subtract `1 seconds` from the `00:00:00` timedelta values in `end_time` column.

```
c = ['start_time', 'end_time']
s, e = df[c].astype(str).apply(pd.to_timedelta).to_numpy().T
e[e == pd.Timedelta(0)] += pd.Timedelta(days=1, seconds=-1)
```

Then for each pair of `start_time` and `end_time` in the dataframe `df` mark the corresponding duplicate intervals using `numpy broadcasting`:

```
m = (s[:, None] >= s) & (e[:, None] <= e)
np.fill_diagonal(m, False)
df['isDupe'] = (m.any(1) & ~df[c].duplicated(keep=False)).view('i1')
```

---

```
# example 1
  start_time  end_time  isDupe
0   00:12:38  01:00:02       0
1   00:55:14  01:00:02       1
2   01:00:02  01:32:40       0
3   01:00:02  01:08:40       1
4   01:41:22  03:56:23       0
5   18:58:26  19:16:49       0
6   20:12:37  20:52:49       0
7   20:55:16  22:02:50       0
8   22:21:24  22:48:50       0
9   23:11:30  00:00:00       0

# example 2
  start_time  end_time  isDupe
0   13:32:54  13:32:55       0
1   13:36:10  13:50:16       0
2   13:37:54  13:38:14       1
3   13:46:38  13:46:45       1
4   13:48:59  13:49:05       1
5   13:50:16  13:50:20       0
6   14:03:39  14:03:49       0
7   15:36:20  15:36:20       0
8   15:46:47  15:46:47       0
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, this is a brilliant answer..this works with many other samples that I have. thanks a lot :)  also thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 3):

Query `duplicated()` and change astype to `int`

```
df['isDup']=(df['Start time'].duplicated(False)|df['End time'].duplicated(False)).astype(int)
```

Or did you need

```
df['isDup']=(df['Start time'].between(df['Start time'].shift(),df['End time'].shift())).astype(int)
```

Comment: thanks. this solution would work only if the timestamp of duplicate entries is the same. For example, at index 1, if the End time had been 01:00:05, this query wouldn't flag index 1 as a duplicate entry. But in fact, this was invalid login as the user had logged in using the second session while he still logged to the first session and exited the second session after the first session exit.

Comment: Need a bit clarity on your question then. Please revise question. Are you happy to include raw data not image. That way it is easier.

Comment: @SaranyaKrishnamurthy you can use `.shift()` to compare if the previous row's time is greater. `df.shift()['End time'] > df['Start time']`

Comment: @wwnde, sure will do. give me some time

Comment: Could you please try `df['isDup']=(df['Start time'].between(df['Start time'].shift(),df['End time'].shift())).astype(int)`

Comment: @DavidErickson, it appears like this seems to work with the current sample I have posted. Let me check with a few other samples. thanks!

Comment: @SaranyaKrishnamurthy, have you checked the eidt

Comment: @SaranyaKrishnamurthy the easiest way to create a reproducible example that takes one minute is to do: `df.to_dict()`. Then, copy and paste that into a new section in your jupyter notebook. Then, highlight all of the data, press tab and copy it and paste it into StackOverflow in your question. Alternatively, you can execute `%qtconsole` in your jupyter notebook and copy the output of `df` and follow the same process. Paste it into a new section, highlight data and press tab. Then paste into SO.

Comment: @DavidErickson, thanks for the quick tip. I have updated the questions with data now

Comment: @wwnde, the only drawback I see with using shift (for this problem) is, I can compare the current record only to the previous/next record. In another sample that I have added, it marks only index 2 as duplicate.

Comment: @wwnde good idea but IMHO here vectorized solution might not be possible ;)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma agreed.. I have just updated the question with my current answer. I have tried to accomplish the same using iteration

Comment: @SaranyaKrishnamurthy Actually i've got one idea but not sure if its  efficient than yours :)..

Comment: @ShubhamSharma do share.. it might help others!

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamSharma. Yes this has to be an iteration. The other thing would be to pull all end times below current row into a list and check if any is less than start in current row. Wanted to delete  my answer but there is so much useful comment to it.

Comment: @wwnde Actually i have found a numpy based solution thinking of adding it...BTW Don't delete the answer mate :)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma please add. We are after the right solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to the above question. However, if there are any efficient way, I would be happy to accept it. Thanks!

```
def getDuplicate(data):
    data['check_time'] = data.iloc[-1]['start_time']
    data['isDup'] = data.apply(lambda x: 1 
                               if (x['start_time'] <= x['check_time']) & (x['check_time'] < x['end_time']) 
                               else 0 
                               , axis = 1)

    return data['isDup'].sum()

limit = 1
df_copy = df.copy()
df['isDup'] = 0

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    data = df_copy.iloc[:limit]
    isDup = getDuplicate(data)
    limit = limit + 1

    if isDup > 1:
        df.at[i, 'isDup'] = 1
    else:
        df.at[i, 'isDup'] = 0
```